# Ubuntu 20.04 and OneDrive

Tags: 20.04

Help Please! I am in the process of establishing my OneDrive connection to my Ubuntu 20.04.2 server. After installing the dependencies, I then attempted to unpack and run a binary file using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i dmd_2.093.1-0_amd64.deb
```

I received the following output:

```
    (Reading database ... 150962 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack dmd_2.093.1-0_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking dmd (2.093.1-0) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive dmd_2.093.1-0_amd64.deb (--install):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/dub', which is also in package dub 1.26.0-0
    dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
    Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     dmd_2.093.1-0_amd64.deb
```

What can I do to eliminate the install errors? What have I missed?

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: Trying to install Onedrive. Have done it previously on an Ubuntu 20.04 build, but encountered this error while attempting to install on the server.

Comment: Where does that package come from? What instructions are you following? Are these valid in the first place? You should be using the Ubuntu software sources and `apt` to stay out of trouble.

Comment: The instructions were found here: https://gist.github.com/starlinq/0f98c6d9339497bb8ac42d67f66f60eb As to their validity, I thought they were valid, as I had no issues installing the packages up to that point. The issue came when I mistakenly followed the 18.04 instructions and tried to roll back those changes, and follow the correct instructions.

Comment: There is a package `onedrive` in Ubuntu's `universe` repositories.  The description is "*folder synchronization with OneDrive*".  Why is this insufficient? Why are you installing this random `.deb` file that you found on the Internet?

Comment: @Nmath So, I'm assuming that your recommendation is to use the onedrive package from the Ubuntu's universe...okay. Can you provide the necessary command syntax to download that software package? Or, could you provide me with a link to describe the process?

Comment: Why wouldn't you?  Since it's in official repos, all you have to do is search and install "onedrive" from your GUI package manager. Or you can use `apt` with `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install onedrive`.  Unfortunately, you possibly created a problem with your earlier actions. It's probably a good idea to revert any changes you made before installing the official client. FYI: downloading and installing `.deb` files from the internet is probably the worst way to install software (and most unsafe) especially if you are not good at solving Linux problems

Comment: > There is a package onedrive in Ubuntu's universe repositories. The description is "folder synchronization with OneDrive". Why is this insufficient? Why are you installing this random .deb file that you found on the Internet?

The packages in Ubuntu Universe are old - they contain bugs and defects and they should not be used. Do not install the application from Ubuntu Universe packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You previously installed the `dub 1.26.0-0` package, which contained `/usr/bin/dub`. How?

Your attempt to install `dmd` from the `.deb` file also contained `/usr/bin/dub` (same? different?), so `dpkg` didn't overwrite the original `/usr/bin/dub`.

Read the error message.

Uninstall `dub` and try again.

Rather than downloading `.deb` files from unofficial sources, I suggest that you use Ubuntu packages. Read `man apt apt-get apt-cache synaptic`.

Comment: @Nmath; Thank you both for the assistance. I reinstalled Ubuntu server to eliminate unwanted system changes caused by my efforts; and will install onedrive using the guidance you've provided.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

@25BG6

> The instructions were found here: gist.github.com/starlinq/0f98c6d9339497bb8ac42d67f66f60eb

Disclosure: I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

These instructions are 100% invalid. Do not follow these instructions.

To install the client on Ubuntu 20.x your only have 2 methods:

1. Use the OpenSuSE Build Service packages as per: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md
2. Build from source using the correct instructions as detailed here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

These are the only methods that work.